# transferring the return value from actionresult to another view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to show the data in a label inside view, the data is coming from another view for that purpose i have did like this

this is my model is

```
namespace MvcSampleApplication.Models
{
    public class products
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Textbox1")]
        public string EnteredValue { get; set; }
    }    
    public class category
    {
        [Display(Name = "Label1")]
        public string lablvalue { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

and this is my controller

```
namespace MvcSampleApplication.Controllers
{
    public class EnterValueController : Controller
    {           
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Valuesadd(MvcSampleApplication.Models.products model)
        {
            return View(model);            
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SubmitValue(MvcSampleApplication.Models.products model)
        {
            ViewData["logindata"] = model.EnteredValue;    
            return View("submittedvalues");               
        }                
        public ActionResult submittedvalues()
        {
            var model = new MvcSampleApplication.Models.category();
            string data = ViewData["logindata"] != null ? ViewData["logindata"].ToString() : "";
            model.lablvalue = data;
            return View(model);            
        }
    }
}
```

and this my view

```
@model MvcSampleApplication.Models.category
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "submittedvalues";
}
<h2>submittedvalues</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>
              Lable value
          </legend>                
            @Html.DisplayFor(s=>s.lablvalue)         
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

when i press the submit button it will be going to view(submittedvalues.cshtml) but not displaying results
Many thanks....

Comment: what i need to write at here @Html.DisplayFor(s=>s.lablvalue)  for showing the value in the label ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your code as, Instead of `return View()` use `RedirectToAction` to redirect it to another action. Also notice that I have used `TempData` instead of `ViewData`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitValue(MvcSampleApplication.Models.products model)
{
    TempData["logindata"] = model.EnteredValue;    
    return RedirectToAction("submittedvalues");               
}                
public ActionResult submittedvalues()
{
    var model = new MvcSampleApplication.Models.category();
    string data = string.IsNullOrEmpty(TempData["logindata"]) ? string.Empty : TempData["logindata"].ToString();
    model.lablvalue = data;
    return View(model);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because this:

```
return View("submittedvalues");
```

immediately renders the view called "submittedvalues.cshtml"

So this code:

```
public ActionResult submittedvalues()
        {
            var model = new MvcSampleApplication.Models.category();
            string data = ViewData["logindata"] != null ? ViewData["logindata"].ToString() : "";
            model.lablvalue = data;
            return View(model);            
        }
```